# Server directory read permissions

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

(1)I'm currently in the process of moving a project to a web host.

(2)I want to install the site into a sub-domain - ie. `sub.domain.com`

(3)I've directed `sub.domain.com` to a sub-directory of the server root: `/sub/public_html`

(4)`/sub` has 2 directories:

```
`public_html` - for the publicly traversable files & directories
`resources` - for sensitive documents
```

(3)I now want:

```
  (a)users to be able to visit `sub.domain.com` and traverse the contents of `public_html`

  (b)users NOT to be able to traverse the contents of 'resources`

  (b)users NOT to be able to view the DIRECT/IMMEDIATE contents of the server root
```

My questions are:

(1) Can this be done with .htaccess?

(2) If so, how?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: `meant /sub/public_html instead of just /sub`

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to change the server root of the subdomain to `sub/public_html` instead of `public_html`. If you don't want user to be able to access anything below that, don't include it the server root. Server-side scripts will still be able to access the directory.

That said, you can do that, with a performance penalty, in a .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^public_html/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^resources - [R=403,L]
RewriteRule .* public_html/$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, what about stopping the issue of a user being able to view every thing by just traversing as domain.com/../..?

Comment: @Tunji Apache won't allow that...